# Laravel Controller get value from ServiceProvider

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have this custom validation in a controller to validate phone numbers,

Controller

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        ...
        'phonenumber' => 'required|phone_number'
    ]);
```

AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot(){
   $this->app['validator']->extend('is_phone', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        ...

        if($rest_result->status == 200){
            // I need this $rest_result->phone_number ;
            return true ;
        }
        return false ;
    });
}
```

I implemented the validator and put it in the `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider` so I can reuse it elsewhere and that works. I use a web service to verify the number and if the call is successful the service formats the number in the corresponding national format which I need in my app.

How do I pass that value back to my controller ?

**Bonus**: It would be really cool if it could also overwrite the value in `old` so that the form gets it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to handle this all in one shot.

After you've done your validation, use the `merge` method on the request to merge the validated and modified input back into the request object.

You would put the following

```
public function boot(){
    $this->app['validator']->extend('is_phone', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        ...

        if($rest_result->status == 200){
            request()->merge(['phone' => $rest_result->phone]);
            return true;
        }
        return false ;
    });
}
```

Now in your controller, that phone would be included with the request...  Obviously the phone number wouldn't be replaced by the phone number returned from the service until you actually make the validation object.

```
$phone = request()->phone;
```

Comment: It should be available when the closure is hit.

Comment: Yeah I think I spoke too fast, I'm trying it out now. I couldn't access the session earlier so I assumed I wouldn't have access to the request either

Comment: I do need it in the controller though, because if it's valid it's going to be saved

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, I couldn't access `Session::FlashInput` though, I had to go through `request()->session()` to save the variable, and even then no access to flash

Comment: You no longer need access to the session.  If you merge it into the request itself, Laravel will automatically flash all that data from the request into the session as long as you are using `redirect()->withInput()`.  Because Laravel will handle that for you, it would then be available to the `old()` function.