# Get AppServiceProvider Boot Variables in Controller

Tags: laravel

I assigned global variables `$currentCountry` and `langStat` in AppServiceProvider.php to use them in views and controllers.

```
public function boot()
{
    $location = geoip(request()->ip());
    $currentCountry = $location->iso_code; // For getting user country.

    view()->share('currentCountry', $currentCountry);

    view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
        $view->with('langStat', '_' . \Session::get('language')); //For getting user language
        App::setlocale(Session::get('language'));
    });
}
```

Fortunately, I am able to use both of those variables in *views* but I get an `undefined` error for both of them when I use those variables in *controllers*.

So, my question is that how can I use those two `variables` inside the controller functions?

Comment: I think you should consider this same question asked here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020579/laravel-controller-get-value-from-serviceprovider"

Comment: It is using the merge and it is different.

Comment: you could set it on the container and get it from the container in the controller ... you could also get it from the view factory ... and other ways as well

Comment: @lagbox I want a global variable to use like this `$variable` in controller and view. I can use like `config['variable']` but I don't like it. I want a clean variable with $

Answer (score 0):

[`Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::share()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) and [`Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::composer()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers) are meant to share data amongst views.

This has nothing to do with sharing data amongst controllers.
I suggest you set the variables in your session instead.

## STEPS:

1. Define a middleware. Run this command to create the middleware template file.
   `php artisan make:middleware Locale`
2. Open the created middleware file (*app/Http/Middleware/Locale.php*) and set the variable(s) in the session.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Locale
{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        $locale = request()->getLocale();
        app()->setLocale($locale);

        session([
            "lang-stat" => $locale,
            "current-country" => geoip(request()->ip())->iso_code,
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

3. Register your middleware.

- Open the file at `app/Http/Kernel.php`
- Add your middleware at the end of the `$middleware` array list.
- This will set the '*current country*' & '*language (lang-stat)*' upon each http request.

```php
// ...
    protected $middleware = [

    // ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,

    ];

// ...
```

Now you can access the variables in any controller by using `session("lang-stat")`.

You can as well access the variables in any view by using `{{session("current-country")}}`